RTEMS build and compile
I'm trying to integrate RTEMS into my project. My project was initially built with GCC toolchain. It currently runs on freeRTOS with stm32f4 as MCU and now I plan to change the real-time OS to RTEMS. However, RTEMS uses a custom cross-toolchain based on GCC. So to use RTEMS I figured the correct way to approach this is to compile the RTEMS using GCC rather than the other way around.
To understand which RTEMS source files are required, I used RTEMS "BSP build guidelines" and built the project using ARM-RTEMS cross-toolchain in Linux, also verified the files using yml instructions written for the source-builder.
Because ARM-RTEMS is based on GCC and what I have noticed as the difference between these two toolchains is some type definitions in the header library, I believe if I give the address of the header library, this difference in the header library is taken care of. May even require some macro and assembly syntax modification, nothing impossible to do, I believe.
I've just started to do the compilation, and I want to ask your opinions if you think this is manageable too. Or if you have any insights.
